# PySpark - list specific files and directories

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have received parquet files for year 2018 and 2019. The data is organized in folders with monthly data under the parent folder(test).

-test/dt=20180101/

-test/dt=20180201/

....

-test/dt=20181201/

-test/dt=20190101/

...

-test/dt=20191201/

How do I -

1. list folders  for year 2018 ?
2. list files under folders for year 2018 ?

I am getting the following error No such file or directory:

Here's the code which I am using

```
%fs ls s3://test/dt=2018*/
```

Comment: add your code snnipet in questin

Comment: added the code snippet

Comment: if you're using databricks DBFS then simply do %fs ls /test/dt=2018*/

Comment: It doesn't work, I am getting error- java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: